# How to use __import__() to import local modules

Tags: python, python-requests

Hi I am packaging urlib and other modules within msazurensg/lib. I found the below code in requests/package.py file.

```
import sys

# This code exists for backwards compatibility reasons.
# I don't like it either. Just look the other way. :)

for package in ('urllib3', 'idna', 'chardet'):
    locals()[package] = __import__(package)
    # This traversal is apparently necessary such that the identities are
    # preserved (requests.packages.urllib3.* is urllib3.*)
    for mod in list(sys.modules):
        if mod == package or mod.startswith(package + '.'):
            sys.modules['requests.packages.' + mod] = sys.modules[mod]

# Kinda cool, though, right?
```

This tries to import the modules from the site-packages directory. I want it to import it as "from msazurensg.lib import urllib".

How do I do this? To be frank I am clueless as to what is happening here.